# Setinterval not working?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, load, setinterval

I'm making a chat, now I want `messages.php` to be reloading whole time, but not the place where you can input your message.

I use this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function()
{
setinterval(function){}
    $("#reload").load("messages.php");,1000);
});
</script>

<div id="reload"></div>
<html>

<form action="sendmessages.php" method="get">
<textarea name="bericht" cols="60" rows="10"></textarea><br>
<input value="verstuur" type="submit">


</form>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4):

The code

```
setinterval(function){}
    $("#reload").load("messages.php");,1000);
```

should be :

```
setInterval(function(){
 $("#reload").load("messages.php");
},1000);
```

Comment: @user3160026 No, you're using `setinterval` instead of `setInterval` and there are other mistakes too.

Comment: @user3160026: Also, note the inclusion of a new closing curly brace (`}`).

Comment: Now i have <script type="text/javascript">
$(function()
{
 setInterval(function){
        $("#reload").load("messages.php");,1000);
});
</script> But it is not working?

Comment: @Downvoter Can you please tell me why you downvoted so that I can fix my answer ?
@user3160026 Look before `,1000` on your code and my code.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function()
    {
 setInterval(function(){
    $("#reload").load("messages.php");
    },1000);
    });
    </script>
It is still wrong :/ dont got it wth??

Comment: No, i dont see messages.php loaded.Messages.php is in the same map.. So it have to work. :(

Comment: How about `$(document).ready(function(){` instead of `$(function(){`

Comment: Nope, this is were i placed it: http://www.game.robinm.nl/messages.php and here is were your code is placed: http://www.game.robinm.nl/chat.php

Comment: @user3160026 You haven't loaded **jQuery** in that page (chat.php).

Comment: <script src="http://www.code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 setInterval(function(){
 $("#reload").load("messages.php");
},1000);
});
</script> doesnt work too?

Comment: <script src="http://www.code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"> Doesnt work too

Answer (score 0):

[setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)

```
setInterval(function(){$("#reload").load("messages.php")},3000);
```

Your syntax is wrong...